# Delete from Many to Many Relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I am not a MySQL professional I am just trying to make simple java application which accesses a MySQL database (e.g. The famous books/authors database) and manipulates it (i.e, add, update, delete).

The problem is that there are two tables that have many to many relationship (e.g. authors table and books table) when I am trying to delete using

```
DELETE FROM tableName WHERE someColumnName = 'someValue'
```

it throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException with the message "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"

I know it's because of the "many to many" relationship but actually I don't know what to do with this since I am not a MySQL professional. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit:**
here's the database

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS books;

CREATE DATABASE books;

USE books;

CREATE TABLE Authors
(
   AuthorID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   FirstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   LastName varchar(30) NOT NULL
)                 ;
CREATE TABLE Titles
(
   ISBN varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   EditionNumber int NOT NULL,
   Copyright varchar(4) NOT NULL
)             ;

CREATE TABLE AuthorISBN
(
   AuthorID int NOT NULL,
   ISBN varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES Authors(AuthorID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) References Titles(ISBN) ON DELETE SET NULL
)            ;

INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Paul','Deitel')           ;
INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Harvey','Deitel')     ;
INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Abbey','Deitel')     ;
INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Michael','Morgano')    ;
INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Eric','Kern')     ;


INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132152134','Visual Basic 2010 How to Program',5,'2011')          ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132152134')     ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132152134') ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132151421','Visual C# 2010 How to Program',4,'2011')  ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132151421')      ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132151421')      ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132575663','Java How to Program',9,'2012')   ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132575663')                                               ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132575663')                                       ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132662361','C++ How to Program',8,'2012')     ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132662361')                                                  ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132662361')                                                 ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132404168','C How to Program',6,'2010')     ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132404168')                                             ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132404168')                                       ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('013705842X','iPhone for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach',1,'2010')        ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'013705842X')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'013705842X')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (3,'013705842X')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (4,'013705842X')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (5,'013705842X')                                                    ;

INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN,Title,EditionNumber,Copyright) VALUES ('0132121360','Android for Programmers: An App-Driven Approach',1,'2012')        ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (1,'0132121360')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (2,'0132121360')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (3,'0132121360')                                                    ;
INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID,ISBN) VALUES (4,'0132121360')                                                    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you set your `CONSTRAINT` `onUpdate` and `onDelete` to `RESTRICT`. You can change it to `SET NULL` and then be able to delete.

See [this section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on MySQL documentation.

**EDIT**

beyond `SET NULL`, you can try `NO ACTION` option as well.

IE:

```
FOREIGN KEY(ord_no,book_id) REFERENCES neworder(ord_no,book_id)  
ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```

OR

```
FOREIGN KEY(ord_no,book_id) REFERENCES neworder(ord_no,book_id)  
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this should be done in the database source file itself right?

Comment: yes. If you have already created the database and you want to add some constraint, just put `ALTER TABLE bookstore ADD` before the code above.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES Authors(AuthorID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (ISBN) References Titles(ISBN) ON DELETE SET NULL`


is this wrong syntax? I get error (42s02) when creating the database

Comment: The sintaxe is ok. Seems like you are assigning the wrong fields in the reference. Edit your question and put the whole `CREATE` sintaxe you are using.